# Toggle between displaying different html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When page loads I am doing some changes to the `html` of a element, I have a toggle button for this element but I have problems to make it work correctly.

What I am trying to do is followin:

When page is loaded the modified `html` will be displayed.
When user click on the toggle button I want the original `html` to be displayed with full text with slide effect.
When user click on the toggle button again I want it to display the modified `html` with slide effect.

I have almost made it to work, it looks like this

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dM7Vd/13/)

Here is the code:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
var string = $('#object-full-description').html();

var place = string.indexOf('.', 800);
if (place >= 0)
{
    $('#object-full-description').html(string.substring(0, place + 1));
}


$('#full-description-toggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.toggled').length > 0) {
      $('#object-full-description').slideToggle('slow', function() {
      $('#full-description-toggle').removeClass('toggled');
      place = string.indexOf('.', 800);
      if (place >= 0) {
      $('#object-full-description').html(string.substring(0, place + 1));
      }
   });
  } else {
    $('#object-full-description').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    $('#full-description-toggle').addClass('toggled');
    $('#object-full-description').html(string);
 });
}
});             
});
```

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: I would appreciate if you add code here. This not expected from a user who has asked 172 question before to just ignore warning.

Comment: A typo `$('full-description-toggle')` missing `#`

Comment: @Satpal Yeah saw it just a miss when i pasted it here, but that doesnt solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/dM7Vd/16/

Looks like you just need to add

```
$('#object-full-description').slideToggle('slow');
```

at the end of your function. You're hiding it but not re-showing it.

Comment: I dont know why that works out on jsfiddle but that line makes it execute two ToggleSlides each time. which is wrong

Comment: Can you tell me why you think it's wrong? http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ "If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown." You're using slideToggle to hide it, then you need to call slideToggle again to show it?

Comment: Beacuse when its going to show then the second that you told me to add will hide it. @artm

Comment: Might be misunderstood here, you're calling slidetoggle once to hide it, then you're changing it's html, then you need to call slidetoggle again (a 2nd time) to show what you've hidden.

Comment: Hmm thats strange beacuse  I have exact same code I added your line, When i click on the button for first time the full html is displayed and then suddenly it slides up and its empty, if I click again on the button same thing happens but this time the changed html is shown instead of empty.